# Why are there so few monitors with 1920x1200 resolution and a HDMI port?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, mac-mini

I'm thinking of buying two monitors with 1920x1200 resolution and plugging them into a Mac mini. The Mac mini has one HDMI port and a mini DVI (thunderbolt?) so I will be using an Mini DVI to HDMI convertor and a direct HDMI cable for the second monitor.

As I began searching for monitors with the required specs, I was intrigued by the fact that only expensive monitors have HDMI at that resolution. All of them have DVI. Where I work we have cheap 1920x1080 monitors and they all have HDMI.

I don't know what to do, really. Is it ok if I purchase one mini DVI to DVI and one HDMI to DVI convertor? Is there any loss by using convertors?

Is there any reason for this? Is HDMI so new that it's not so widely used yet?

Comment: Mini-DVI isn't Thunderbolt.  Thunderbolt is Thunderbolt...Why wouldn't you use a HDMI to DVI cable instead?

Comment: They are somewhat compatible and that's why I wrote mini DVI - because I will probably not use the benefits of the thunderbolt technology. I can plug a mini DVI cable in the thunderbolt and pretend it's mini DVI. http://www.journaldulapin.com/2012/12/12/thunderbolt-and-mini-displayport-differences-and-compatibility/

Comment: Most people opt for the typical TV-aspect ratio of 16:9 as opposed to 16:10, which is unfortunate for people like you and me whom prefer the 16:10 aspect ratio (I think it's superior for document work).  That being said, I know off-hand that both Dell, NEC, and ASUS offer several monitors each fitting your specifications (the Dell/ASUS are all IPS panels, and NEC has both TN and IPS panels at that resolution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using an adapter betweeen DVI/HDMI/DisplayPort there is no loss of signal, as they are all digital.